# API for finding the category of a domain

Tags: java, web-services, categories

Is there an API for finding the category of a domain? I'm looking for an alternative to reading the website's `meta` tags with [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

For example a query with `allmusic.com` should yield `music`, while one for `arsenal.com` should yield `sports`.

The ideal candidate can be used easily with Java. :-)

P. S: The system does **not** have to be perfect.

Comment: only google would be able to do such categorization ..

Comment: @LeosLiterak I know that at least [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) has such a system too. But unfortunately no API. :-(

Comment: OpenDNS has switched to Cisco Umbrella, with an API (https://docs.umbrella.com/developer/investigate-api/domain-status-and-categorization-1/) , but it's not free of charge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These should help:

- http://www.similarweb.com/pricing
- https://www.webshrinker.com/
- https://zvelo.com/zvelo-products/zvelodb/
- https://aws.amazon.com/awis/

All of those allow you to get Categories for a given domain. Not free, but then that was not specified.

Comment: AWIS is free for 1000 requests/month, so that may comply with «free of charge» :-)

Comment: AWIS does not return category.
I finally try github.com/wchan757/similarweb_scraper

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I could use [Wikipedia's API](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php) to find an article and then look at its categories.

Comment: OK, that's not working out that good. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I have to rely on my old idea, which scans the website's `meta` tags and its URL.